# git lfs not working - still throwing error - remote: error: GH001: Large files detected

Tags: git, git-lfs

So I used node in my rails projects and there is this file that github won't push as it exceeds 100MB:

> node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-856583/chrome-linux/chrome

I did

```
git lfs install
git lfs track "/node_modules/*"
git add .gitattributes
git add .
git commit -am "commit after lfs"
git push
```

But it still throws the same error:

```
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: d06553d5a0051916cd0d22b28f55bb105cb07d442b1a6f6133e51e888e22b221
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-856583/chrome-linux/chrome is 274.64 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

I also checked using git lfs ls-files and I see that file
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When you decide to use LFS to hold large files, you must *migrate* existing commits to new commits, so that the old commits that have the large files are no longer being used. All you did here was make a *new* commit that omits the large file (having it on the large-file-server instead) but *keep the old commits* that *do* have the large file (instead of having it on the large-file-server).

Comment: (I do not use Git-LFS with any regularity and do not have a migration recipe for you, but I believe the Git-LFS documentation does.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve this issue I had to first undo the previous commit:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

Answer (score 3):

You need first do `git lfs push` to push all the LFS files.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem after %88 it was stuck and didn't complete the uploading process.

That's what I've tried and solved;

> The Git LFS integrity check ensures that all referenced Git LFS files
> in a push have been uploaded properly. If the check detects referenced
> files that have not been uploaded, you will receive an error message
> and your push will be blocked.
>
> To resolve the error message, you must reinstall your local Git LFS
> client to ensure that the referenced Git LFS files can be properly
> uploaded in the future.

```
Open Terminal
```

Reinstall Git LFS

```
git lfs install
```

Push all referenced Git LFS files

```
git lfs push --all origin
```